# How to read and write "Excel" with c/c++ (in smartphone app develop)

Tags: c++, c, cocos2d-x

I'm a smartphone app developer.
I want to make a app running in iOS,android,winphone.
I use cocos2d-x platform tool to make this app. it base of c/c++ language.
So,
Dose anyone can tell me How to read and write excel with c/c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what purpose? Just reading the file can be done by treating it as an opaque stream of bytes, just like any other file.

I doubt that's what you really mean, though.

If you want to *interpret* the file's contents, and present/update the calculations, then surely you must realize that the answer to "how" that is done must be gigantic? Excel is a huge, huge, and very old application, probably the result of many millions of lines of code.

Nobody can tell you "how" to interpret that in a simple answer here.

The closest thing you can probably get here is a recommendation on a library to use. I had a quick look, and [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) was the first one I found for C++. It is a commercial library, and I have no experience with it.

Comment: thank you very much.I will try "LibXL".In fact I means how to read and input data from excel file.